# How to display data frame in template page using django

Tags: python, django, pandas, templates

I am trying to populate my data frame in Django, But I am getting a blank page.

Here I am sharing my sample code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>API Display</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List of Data </h1>
    {% for i in d %}
    <strong>{{i}}</strong>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

```
def index(request):
    url = "http://153.24.76.45:9000/abc/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    z = response.json()
    # df = z.reset_index().to_json(orient ='records')
    df = pd.DataFrame(z['Result']['LSData'])
    
    context = {'d': df}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Try inserting space before and after variable: `{{ i }}`

Comment: Use `context = {'d': df.to_html()}`. This creates an html table, that you can style with css. In your template, use `{{d | safe}}`